# Local Flink Job Failed With OOM

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running a Flink job locally from an IDE (Intellij IDEA) that consumes messages from two or more Kafka topics and it fails with `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. The Kafka cluster/broker is remote and on each topic there are no more than 10 messages. I tried to increase/set heap memory via `-Xms` and `-Xmx` while starting the Flink job but it did not help. Just wondering is there is any place where I can change/set memory for the local Flink job or any other way I can resolve this issue.

Comment: I'd suggest including the full stack trace for the OOME, so that it's more obvious what's triggering the error.

Comment: Actually, there is no exception stack trace, all I got was a simple error message as I described above. I tried to increase the heap memory via Xmx setting it to 8GB and that did not help.